Google python SDK not setting scopes correctly
I am trying to use the google python SDK in order to get all the groups a given user is part of, however I am having issues with setting the scopes of the credentials which would be making the API call.
Currently the relevant piece of code looks like this:
    creds, project = google.auth.default(scopes=["https://www.googleapis.com/auth/admin.directory.user.readonly", "https://www.googleapis.com/auth/admin.directory.group.readonly"])
    creds.refresh(Request())
    service = build("admin", "directory_v1", credentials=creds)
    results = service.groups().list(domain="sky.uk",userKey=USER_EMAIL, maxResults=400).execute()

However, this results in the following error message:
googleapiclient.errors.HttpError: <HttpError 403 when requesting https://admin.googleapis.com/admin/directory/v1/groups?domain=sky.uk&userKey=USER_EMAIL&maxResults=400&alt=json returned "Request had insufficient authentication scopes.". Details: "[{'message': 'Insufficient Permission', 'domain': 'global', 'reason': 'insufficientPermissions'}]">

Inspecting the credentials being used, it appears as if the scopes I am declaring are not actually being set, as on the token it is just
  "scope": "https://www.googleapis.com/auth/cloud-platform https://www.googleapis.com/auth/sqlservice.login https://www.googleapis.com/auth/userinfo.email openid",
I am not quite sure what I am doing wrong here and would be grateful if someone could point me in the right direction
Tried deleting local credentials, and rerunning the code but no effect. I've tried adding other scopes but they also do not seem to get set

I suspect it's your service account. Is the account configured for domain-wide delegation? You won't be able to access Google Workspace user credentials without it.

First, kindly make sure you have the prerequisites checked:


Python 3.10.7 or greater

The pip package management tool

A Google Cloud project.

A Google Workspace domain with API access enabled.

A Google Account in that domain with administrator privileges.



Some common issues is that the Directory API is not enabled.
You may also try the code sample provided in the documentation. You can try using the https://www.googleapis.com/auth/admin.directory.user scope instead.
